# how to drag an item, but it should still remain in its original place?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a drag and drop code. I want to drag an item, and at the same time it should leave a copy in draggable list.
for e.g

```
list1         
aa
bb
cc

list2
zz
xx
mm
```

so I want to drag *aa* to list2 , but *aa* should remain in the list.

```
$('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
   connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list'
});
```

```
<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-3">
<div class="dhe-example-section-content">
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.3 -->

<div id="example-1-3">

<ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable">
<li class="sortable-item">Deposit INterest</li>
<li class="sortable-item">GDP% of total</li>
<li class="sortable-item">GDP curr($)</li>
<li class="sortable-item">Health exp</li>
</ul>

</div>

<!-- END: XHTML for example 1.3 -->

</div>
</div><br><br>  
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-4">
<div class="dhe-example-section-content" >
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.4 -->
<div id="example-1-4">
<div class="column left first">

<ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable"><br>
<li class="sortable-item">Sortable item A</li>
<li class="sortable-item">Sortable item B</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: whats the problem now ?

Comment: how to make the copy..?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `.draggable()` and `.sortable()` this way to achieve your need. may be this can help you for this:

```
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
   connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list',
   revert: true
}).disableSelection();

$('.sortable-list li').draggable({ //<------------make the list items draggables
   connectToSortable: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list', //<---this is v.imp
   helper : "clone"  //<-------------------------------use this to get a copy
});
```

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erjey/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is helpers that are displayed when you start dragging: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper

```
$('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
   connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list',
   helper: "clone"
});
```

It should display a clone when dragging and leave original in place

Comment: yes i tried that already, but with this all items get cloned.
i.e 4x4 items. there are so many items then. I want that i should be able to drag again and again, but it should remain in its original place.